# Magento 2 getting errors on all page Unable to process binding "attr: function

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am getting errors on all pages anyone knows please give me solutions on how to fix it. Please check screenshot

[image]

**Errors**:-

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "attr: function(){return {
name:inputName,cols:cols,rows:rows,'aria-describedby':noticeId,placeholder:placeholder,id:uid,disabled:disabled} }"
Message: cols is not defined**